# compile ffmpeg with android ndk r5b

Tags: android, ffmpeg, configure, android-ndk

compile ffmpeg with android ndk r5b.

ffmpeg 0.6.1

android ndk r5b

cygwin 1.7

build reference url : http://www.cnblogs.com/scottwong/archive/2010/12/17/1909455.html

but, ffmpeg ./configure result error! (below config.err file)

```
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.GlDiY1P8.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.GlDiY1P8.c
/android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-eabi-gcc -fPIC -DANDROID -c -o /tmp/ffconf.1kQLpGaU.o /tmp/ffconf.GlDiY1P8.c
arm-eabi-gcc.exe: /tmp/ffconf.GlDiY1P8.c: No such file or directory

arm-eabi-gcc.exe: no input files

C compiler test failed.
```

so, i just try test code.

```
// test.c code
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

/android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-eabi-gcc -fPIC -DANDROID -c -o ./test.o ./test.c

ok!!!! no problem.

but, 
cp ./test.c /tmp (copy to /tmp)

/android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-eabi-gcc -fPIC -DANDROID -c -o ./test.o /tmp/test.c

```
arm-eabi-gcc.exe: /tmp/test.c: No such file or directory
arm-eabi-gcc.exe: no input files
```

fail!!! 
difference is only file path. /tmp directory exist, and permission is right. /home/test.c is same result.

what's wrong?

Comment: did u succeed in resolving the above issue? If so, could you please share the solution?

Answer (score 6):

I have had a hard time to get it working in Windows, but finally I've managed to do it!
The previous posts were correct - there's a problem with Cygwin paths and Windows paths.
I have tried the solution described in the post above as the very first thing, but it was not working. Finally I've understand the reason: even if you put into your build_android.sh file the Windows path, the config for FFmpeg still contains the wrong path.

So in my case I have changed partially the config file in FFmpeg root directory from:

```
#set temporary file name
: ${TMPDIR:=$TEMPDIR} 
: ${TMPDIR:=$TMP}
: ${TMPDIR:=/tmp}
```

to this:

```
# set temporary file name
#: ${TMPDIR:=$TEMPDIR}
#: ${TMPDIR:=$TMP}
: ${TMPDIR:=D:/InstallTools/Android/Cygwin_Root/tmp}
```

After this, I got it compiling.

Comment: There is no config file in ffmpeg. you mean configure ?

Comment: i am executing ./build_android.sh then it gives me error message that "permission denied" what mistake i have done .

Answer (score 3):

You don't set the tmp directory. You can set it in /etc/profile or just in the terminal with `export TMPDIR=/your/tmp/directory`.
Notice:
1. If you compile with cygwin, the directory must be like D:/tmp. You can't use /cygdrive/d/tmp.
2. You must have the permission of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get this to work either, I had the exact same problem. However I was able to compile using "android-ndk-r4".  I am not sure at the moment what is causing the problem but if I ever get around to figuring it out I'll post that too.

So for now workaround is to use ndk r4.

Comment: how did you mention path while using ndk-r4?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to build it, using NDK R6, cygwin. Indeed, it does not support */cydrive/* paths, simply use paths like windows; example below:

```
NDK=e:/AndroidSDK/NDK6
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows
```

Comment: can you please share the config.sh file you used to build ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not solved this problem, check the last part of config.log in the ffmpeg directory; it is most likely a path or CC parameter problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the exact same problem with r6. I have tried Lambage's suggestion with r4 but still could not get this to work.

I have been looking into the problem quite a lot and I think I've discovered the reason.

1)configure is calling the android cross compiler which is a windows .exe file.

2)It is calling it through cygwin which uses unix file naming conventions. E.G /cygdrive/c/directory instead of C:\directory

3)It says in the android NDK toolchain documentation that the cross compilers do NOT accept cygwin style filepaths (source: NDK/docs/STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN.html):

---

### 5.1/ Windows support:

The Windows binaries do *not* depend on Cygwin. The good news is that they
are thus faster, the bad news is that they do not understand the Cygwin
path specification like /cygdrive/c/foo/bar (instead of C:/foo/bar).

---

I'm still trying to find a way to do this. If i solve it then I'll come back and edit this post...tbc