# Using FFmpeg with Android-NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I want to use `FFmpeg` with `Android-NDK` and I am very basic in this section, I need some help and I research about this topic before on the net, but got no satisfactory solution.

1 - How can I use `FFmpeg` through Windows OS. (I do not want to use Ubuntu, please do not suggest.)

2 - How can I inset `FFmpeg` commands via `NDK`?

Last notice : I using `android-ndk-r7b` and `Cygwin`.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: iSUn did u solve this issue? do i have to compile ffmpeg to run it's commands on android? or can i run it w/o compiling it? can u please explain me a procedure?

Comment: @ChaitanyaChandurkar Sure, You have to compile it first, put the compiled file into your mobile phone and change the permission to chmod 775 and then you can run commands with exec() method.

Comment: Hi @iSun.. Did you complete the process completly? Can you give a explanation how to use fmpeg in android using windows OS?? I am trying to compress the video using ffmpeg. But I can't find any proper documantations for developing using windows OS. Can you give me any sample??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From your question it is hard to tell what exactly you want/need... so here some general information:

- [Using FFmpeg with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android/4820282#4820282)
- [Good starting point for FFmpeg on Android based on ndkr5](https://github.com/havlenapetr/FFMpeg/commits/debug)
- [Another good starting point for building FFmpeg for Android](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/)
- Helpful information to build FFmpeg for android see [here](http://odroid.foros-phpbb.com/t338-ffmpeg-compiled-with-android-ndk), [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/bd054e9f58b277d8) and [here](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Issue-with-cross-compiling-ffmpeg-for-linux-in-windows-td3830825.html)
- [Make sure that you use Windows paths instead of `/cydrive...` when doing ffmpeg/android/cygwin/windows dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002338/847363)

If you need further help please explain exactly what you want to achieve and what is not working...

**UPDATE - as per comments:**

To use ffmpeg via command line on Android you need to copy ffmpeg into your application's `files` directory and `chmod 755` it using `getRuntime.exec()` then you can run ffmpeg with the following line for example:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/yourpackagename/files/ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 outfile.mp4")
```

Comment: @iSun When I asked you said you want to use commandline... now you are saying you want to use ffmpeg.so which is very different and complicated (needs JNI and other stuff!)... what exactly do you need ?

Comment: @iSun I mean all relevant files to run the ffmpeg command... I can't answer what exactly to copy because this depends on how you compiled and linked ffmpeg (static versus dynamic, which codecs/options etc.).

Comment: Yahia How can i set ffmpeg to chmod 755 on windows?

Comment: @iSun I don't understand... why on Windows ? you said you develop on Windows and want to execute ffmpeg on the android phone...

Comment: Aha, I think you said I have to set ffmpeg folder to chmod 755 before moving to my phone.

Comment: Yahia !! How can i copy ffmpeg library (directory) to /data/data/packagename/files/ ??? in DDMS der is no option to copy entire directory

Comment: youn mean ffmpeg directory should be copied to /data/data/packagename/files/  OR der is one single file which i should copy?

Comment: @Yahia Your last solution using Runtime.getRuntime.exec is only for rooted devices?? Because I've tried your solution in non-routed devices and I've executed: 
/data/data/com.example.test/files/ffmpeg -i sdcard/DCIM/f.mp4 -vf \"transpose=1\" -r 24 -sameq sdcard/DCIM/f2.mp4"

But the logcat says me: permision denied

Comment: @Yahia What type of permissions I need to setup?? Do I need to include some permission in the manifest? I need to convert any video in my Android application and any terminal.

Comment: @beni sorry, but I don't have access to a device currently so I can't check those details...

Comment: @Yahia Thanks. But, Do you think it's possible to use this method to use the ffmpeg library without using your first solution, compile the ffmpeg library to obtain the .so


I've searched information and I didn't find out nothing. So, I gonna to try to compile the ffmpeg library (Your first solution).

Comment: @iSun Could you execute the ffmpeg library using the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method? Because I've tried to use this method and the logcat returned me: permision denied.

Comment: @iSun Yes, I put chmod 777 in the two folders, and I obtain the same output: permission denied. I copy the two code lines: 

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777 /mnt/sdcard/DCIM");

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/ffmpeg -i /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/f.mp4 -vf \"transpose=1\" -r 24 -sameq /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/f2.mp4");

p.waitFor();

Could you execute this in the end?

Comment: @iSun I put the chmod in the exec() method, but when I check the permissions the contented folder and the file have only -rw, but I put the 777 parameter in the chmod method. So, the file don't have execute permission, I can't change this permission.

Comment: @iSun No, a comment above said it's not needed to have a rooted phone. So, I've tried to execute the ffmpeg program but I couldn't

Comment: @beni  did u succeed running ffmpeg commands??? m stuck at permission problem. same thing. permission denied.

Comment: @ChaitanyaChandurkar No, I've not succeed running ffmpeg commands. I've compiled the ffmpeg with NDK, cause I read only rooted devices can run the ffmpeg executable.

Comment: so is there any other way to run ffmpeg commands in android on non-rooted devices??

Comment: @beni How can you change your android data permission when your phone not rooted ?!

Comment: @iSun This solution only is good if the device is rooted. So, you can't publish an app with this method cause you need to push the ffmpeg executable on the device in develop time.

Comment: @iSun Yes, you've another way if you wanna publish an app, you can open ffmpeg.c file and then find the main function and change it to JNI interface, then you can invoke those JNI functions in your app but you couldn't use commands directly !

Comment: @iSun, how could I use the ffmpeg commands in the ffmpeg.c file?? How could I invoke this command "ffmpeg -i sdcard/DCIM/in.mp4 -s 480x320 sdcard/output.mp4"?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

I made a tutorial on how to build `ffmpeg` and `x264` for `android`:
http://db.tt/TjMqIF3u

You can also download the zip file containing the files you need to make an application on `android` and also an executable of lastest `ffmpeg` to run on `android`.

EDIT: This is really old code and old compilation process. You can find a more up to date process on [FFMPEG docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android)

Comment: HI. I have problems using it... can you please give me an example of using it ? a ffmpeg command thanks.

Comment: I'll try to be more explicit:
I'm using the so and bin file and this command in Android app:
`String[] ffmpegCommand = {"/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ffmpeg","-f", "image2", "-r", "1/5", "-i",  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/frames/frame_%d.jpg", "-c:v", "libx264", "-r", "30",                       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/frames/video.mp4"};`

Comment: With this command I'm receiving `"Unknown input format: 'image2'"`.
Removing `"-f", "image2"`, I'm receiving `"/mnt/sdcard/frames/frame_%d.jpg: Protocol not found"`
and I'm stuck here. 

I'm using this Android code: https://github.com/vanevery/Android-MJPEG-Video-Capture-FFMPEG

Comment: I think I found the problem: you specified only `--enable-protocol=rtp \` - meaning that only rtp protocol can be used - this is what I understand from this, but I need to use `Output:` protocol :| . unfortunately I cannot compile ffmpeg since I'm under windows.. can I ask you a favor in compiling using `--enable-protocol=Output:` ? thanks a lot.

Comment: So, I was able to compile using `--enable-protocol=file \ ` and this resolved the issue related to  `Protocol not found `, but now I'm having another issue: `/mnt/sdcard/frames/frame_%d.jpg: No such file or directory`. I have all permissions in Android application. Do you know what can be wrong now? Any help is more than welcome. Thanks

Comment: i have downloaded .so file that you have provided. now how can i execute FFmpeg command. ex. converting images to video

Comment: i am unable to open the link. can you please update the same. all though the question is old searching leads to this thread. so its better you update it.

Comment: Please check https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android for up to date documentation