# Android VOIP How to stream audio and video on voice chat

Tags: android, voip

I am looking to develop an app, that can make an audio call using sip and then user A (the caller) plays a media file from his android phone and user b (the receiver) can also hear the audio and video in realtime, how i can accomplish this? can we transfer media sounds through sip or voip without using mic? that is a sound of media playing on device's media player, any guidance or links to study will be helpful.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to develop an app, that can make an audio call using sip

Yes, [`Android's SIP package`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html) has that facility built-in for you.

> user A (the caller) plays a media file from his android phone and user
>   b (the receiver) can also hear the audio and video in realtime, how i
>   can accomplish this?

As for streaming the video, you need [`RTSP`](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/rtsp/faq.html) instead of SIP. Have a look at [Video streaming using RTSP: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186950/video-streaming-using-rtsp-android)

Further Reading:
[Upload live android webcam video to RTP/RTSP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281761/upload-live-android-webcam-video-to-rtp-rtsp-server)
[Creating RTP Packets from Android Camera to Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332532/creating-rtp-packets-from-android-camera-to-send)

Library:
https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Comment: thanks for your reply, RTSP is for video, can we transmit audio playing in a media player from caller's phone to receiver's phone, not the media file but audio itself in realtime? any guidance will be appreciated.thanks!