# ffmpeg android unable to build

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, h.264

My goal is to build `ffmpeg static libraries` so that i can use them with jni and call directly the functions defined in ffmpeg to encode series of images as h264 video stream and render it on screen using GLSurfaceVIew in android 2.3.6.

Using https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/api-example_8c-source.html i came to know that by having the required .so files and headers i can do that.

I followed [Android NDK & FFMPEG build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897066/android-ndk-ffmpeg-build?rq=1) and many others. Everywhere i found reference to the build scripts by roman10.

I use Ubunthu 12.0.4 LTS with android-ndk-r9 and ffmpeg-0.10 source!

Below is the built script i used!

```
NDK=~/android-ndk-r9
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
#PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86

function build_one
{
./configure --target-os=linux \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-cross-compile \
--extra-libs="-lgcc" \
--arch=arm \
--cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8 \
--cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \   
--nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
--sysroot=$PLATFORM \
--extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
--disable-everything \
--enable-demuxer=mov \
--enable-demuxer=h264 \
--disable-ffplay \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-avformat \
--enable-avcodec \
--enable-decoder=rawvideo \
--enable-decoder=mjpeg \
--enable-decoder=h263 \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
--enable-decoder=h264 \
--enable-parser=h264 \
--disable-network \
--enable-zlib \
--disable-avfilter \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-asm \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

make clean
make  -j4 install
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
}


#arm v7vfpv3
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=$CPU "
PREFIX=./android/$CPU
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
build_one
```

When i run the script( `test_build.sh`) i get following

```
Unknown option "".
See ./configure --help for available options.
./test_build.sh: line 34: --nm=/home/user/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm: No such file or directory
CC      ffmpeg.o
CC      cmdutils.o
CC      libavdevice/alldevices.o
CC      libavdevice/avdevice.o
CC      libavdevice/dv1394.o
ffmpeg.c: In function âopt_input_fileâ:
ffmpeg.c:3698:9: warning: âloop_inputâ is deprecated (declared at libavformat/avformat.h:1049) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ffmpeg.c: In function âopt_output_fileâ:
ffmpeg.c:4483:9: warning: âloop_outputâ is deprecated (declared at libavformat/avformat.h:1025) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
CC      libavdevice/fbdev.o
CC      libavdevice/lavfi.o
CC      libavdevice/oss_audio.o
CC      libavdevice/v4l2.o
CC      libavfilter/af_aconvert.o
libavfilter/af_aconvert.c:53:5: warning: function declaration isnât a prototype[-Wstrict-prototypes]
libavfilter/af_aconvert.c:105:5: warning: function declaration isnât a prototype[-Wstrict-prototypes]
CC      libavfilter/af_aformat.o
CC      libavfilter/af_amerge.o
CC      libavfilter/af_anull.o
CC      libavfilter/af_aresample.o
CC      libavfilter/af_ashowinfo.o
CC      libavfilter/af_asplit.o
CC      libavfilter/af_astreamsync.o
CC      libavfilter/af_earwax.o
CC      libavfilter/af_pan.o
CC      libavfilter/af_silencedetect.o
CC      libavfilter/af_volume.o
CC      libavfilter/allfilters.o
CC      libavfilter/asink_anullsink.o
libavfilter/af_volume.c: In function âfilter_samplesâ:
./libavutil/arm/intmath.h:104:5: error: invalid 'asm': invalid operand code 'R'
./libavutil/arm/intmath.h:104:5: error: invalid 'asm': invalid operand code 'R'
make: *** [libavfilter/af_volume.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
./test_build.sh: line 61: /home/user/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar: cannot execute binary file
./test_build.sh: line 62: /home/user/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: cannot  binary file
```

How can i get it work, or am i trying in wrong way? Any help is appriciated!!

Also if some one point me out the reason for errors. I dont' know why nm is showing error although it exist on specified path!
Thank You

Comment: Configure ran successfully,creating config.h and config.mak, but now ld gives some error!

Comment: The error is : `unrecognized option '-Wl,-soname,libavutil.so.54'`