# difference between prebuild tool-chain and custom tool-chain compilers in android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cross-compiling, icu

so I'm trying to figure out how to build ICU for android. Initially I tryed to make it with standalone tool-chain, and after some battles I was able to do that at least for x86_64 arch (didn't try with others). However I don't want to have fully custom build system so I decide to figure out how to make it with prebuild toolchains. And I found that it's behave very different - which is very strange. So this was my command when I actually try to configure ICU with standalone tool-chain:

> icu/source/configure --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-dyload
>   --disable-extras --disable-tests --disable-samples --prefix=/icu/build --host=x86_64-linux-android --with-cross-build=/toplay/icu/icu_linux CC=/custom_toolchain/bin/clang
>   CXX=/custom_toolchain/bin/clang++
>   LD=/custom_toolchain/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld
>   AR=/custom_toolchain/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ar
>   CFLAGS="-fPIC -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections"
>   CXXFLAGS="-fPIC -DANDROID -frtti -fno-exceptions -fdata-sections
>   -ffunction-sections"

So, having all the same command, but only changing compilers and tools from prebuild toolchain which will look like:

> icu/source/configure --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-dyload
>   --disable-extras --disable-tests --disable-samples --prefix=/icu/build --host=x86_64-linux-android --with-cross-build=/toplay/icu/icu_linux CC=/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
>   CXX=/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++
>   LD=/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld
>   AR=/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64//bin/x86_64-linux-android-ar
>   CFLAGS="-fPIC -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections"
>   CXXFLAGS="-fPIC -DANDROID -frtti -fno-exceptions -fdata-sections
>   -ffunction-sections"

I get very different configure step results. Which I placed **[there:](https://www.diffchecker.com/lWDAtznN)** (**TLDR:** main diff: in prebuild tool-chain case system can't understand that it's cross-compile mode, it's find `nl_langinfo`, `strtod_l` which isn't available in android) And if standalone tool-chain initially could build ICU, in prebuild case build process eventually broke.

So my question: *what is the difference between compilers and tools in prebuild and standalone case and what flags/settings I need to add to make it work in prebuild case?*

Comment: I found it useful to run `configure` from arch-specific directories, e.g. from `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/icu`, and then I can perform it as one step of the global **`ndk-build`**. See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42964186/192373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. I've answered this on [our bugtracker](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/389#issuecomment-300357633).

> Our Clang defaults to targeting x86 Linux, not any flavor of Android. Setting up your target flags is one of the many things standalone toolchains do.
>
> I'm not really sure what problem you're trying to solve. Whatever you get working with autoconf is going to essentially be a cobbled together standalone toolchain. Standalone toolchains exist entirely for dealing with this kind of scenario.

To answer your specific question here:

> what is the difference between compilers and tools in prebuild and standalone case and what flags/settings I need to add to make it work in prebuild case?

Standalone toolchains are the prebuilt toolchains with a different directory layout (so the compilers can infer the locations of binutils, the sysroot, and the STL) and a few default flags (like `-target` for Clang). If you were to get this working, you'd have just reinvented this wheel (possibly by using `-gcc-toolchain` and a bunch of `--sysroot`, `-isystem`, `-L` stuff rather than changing the directory structure.

In case "why doesn't this work out of the box?" is a follow up question, remember that in Android you have many architectures, even more target versions of the OS, and a handful of STLs to choose from. Neither Clang nor GCC can currently be set up in a way that it can deal with all of Android's variations (long term I do expect to change that, but that's quite a ways down [the road](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/Roadmap.md#Make-standalone-toolchains-obsolete)).