# Building ffmpeg with an executable output

Tags: c++, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I generally don't like to ask such "you figure it out for me" questions, but I suspect this one will be really simple for a C++ guru.  I want to build ffmpeg for Android, and I'd like it to output an executable rather than a set of libraries.

We've been using the guardian project's build:

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

It does produce what we want, but I've found tweaking it for different architectures to be, at best, unpleasant.

I've gotten this version to build:

https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg

It does a nice job of slicing and dicing different architectures, but produces a jni version.

There is a long story as to why I want the exe, but I'll skip it for now.  Is there a flag that needs to be flipped?  Some path or other setting?  I am at this point fully baffled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/jni/Android.mk

Comment: above is a good example of creating android ffmpeg execuatable from static libs. Guardian is a good, solid ffmpeg for android.

Comment: Here's one good example on how to build and run FFmpeg binaries on Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605757/using-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk/9681231#9681231.

Comment: @user2448027 All of them are SO libraries. Kevin says executable; A command line ffmepg for ARM processors.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [scratchbox](http://scratchbox.org/) to **statically** cross-compile for ARM (and test) FFMPEG to your requirements on your desktop (still inside [SB](http://scratchbox.org/)).
Once your happy, get enough space on your droid to keep the larger than otherwise binary and `adb` that exe up in there. Don't forget to `chmod +x`

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605757/using-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk/9681231#9681231) I posted earlier in the comments has lots of general information about FFmpeg and Android. Then there is [Estevex's tutorial](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22605641/ffmpeg_android/main.html) on Android, FFmpeg and x264. In addition, [here's](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/) Roman10's blog post about the subject.

When you manage to build the binaries, remember to set rights to the files (e.g. `chmod 777` or `chmod 775`). The command to run FFmpeg is

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/yourpackagename/files/ffmpeg")
```

**Links**

Some implementations:

- https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg
- https://github.com/havlenapetr/FFMpeg

Discussion:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/vQVOn1iyd9g
- http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Issue-with-cross-compiling-ffmpeg-for-linux-in-windows-td3830825.html