# Combine Audio with Video - Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app to capture video and download audio. I am able to save these files separately but could not find a way to combine these files to make a new video with audio.

Video file is in .mp4 format and audio is in .mp3 format. They have exact same length.

Is there any way to combine these files? I have tried but could not find a way to combine two files.

Also I can do it with FFMPEG but didn't get any best way how to implement this. Please help me out, I'm new in android.

Answer (score 4):

I think [MP4Parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) library is apt for this scenario. I'd found the below sample code to merge audio and video into single mp4 file in this link [Video Recording And Processing In Android](http://andrey.chernih.me/2014/06/28/video-recording-and-processing-in-android/) .

```
public class Mp4ParserAudioMuxer implements AudioMuxer {
    @Override
    public boolean mux(String videoFile, String audioFile, String outputFile) {
        Movie video;
        try {
            video = new MovieCreator().build(videoFile);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        Movie audio;
        try {
            audio = new MovieCreator().build(audioFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        Track audioTrack = audio.getTracks().get(0);
        video.addTrack(audioTrack);

        Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(video);

        FileOutputStream fos;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        BufferedWritableFileByteChannel byteBufferByteChannel = 
            new BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(fos);

        try {
            out.writeContainer(byteBufferByteChannel);
            byteBufferByteChannel.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

If you are thinking of doing it via ffmpeg, you can use [static ffmpeg binaries](https://github.com/JayH5/android-ffmpeg-cmdline/tree/master/res/raw) or [you need to build it](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/).

Comment: I'm not getting this properly, how can I merge both file to create new mp4.

One more thing, I think FFMPEG only work through NDK, or we can integrate this via SDK too in Eclipse? Please help me as I'm just a fresher in Android Development.

Comment: @AndrewRyan Had you tried the code?. Regarding FFMpeg we can integrate via SDK too. Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605757/using-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk/9681231#9681231

Comment: yes I've tried all that stuff, I save file from camera as .mp4 now I've two files 1 is .mp4 and another 1 .mp3, now what else I need to do for creating new mp4?
even I've used that above code but not able to convert or create a new mp4 file.

Comment: @AndrewRyan :- Have you got Result?, actually i want to create new mp4 file , when merge 1 is mp4 and another 1 .mp3 ..

Comment: @b1izzard  in this code i got Exception like this.. :-"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.coremedia.iso.boxes.MovieBox.getBoxes(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference –" how can i Resolve?

Comment: @AndrewRyan :-  in this code i got Exception like this.. :-"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.coremedia.iso.boxes.MovieBox.getBoxes(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference –" how can i Resolve?