# How to bind different pixels video files and an audio file from a xml response

Tags: android

I got a xml response string which has videos with different pixels and an audio file. I extract all different videos and an audio. I wanna know is how to bind the audio file to those different videos. Now videos are playing well without sound.

---

Video Files in mimeType="video/mp4"

- 144p
- 240p
- 360p
- 480p
- 720p
- 1080p

Audio file in mimeType="audio/mp4"

---

XML String is like this:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MPD
xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
minBufferTime="PT1.500S"
type="static"
mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M15.348S"
maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M2.000S" 
profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011,http://dashif.org/guidelines/dash264">
<Period duration="PT0H0M15.348S">
<AdaptationSet
segmentAlignment="true"
maxWidth="720"
maxHeight="1280"
maxFrameRate="30"
par="360:640"
lang="und"
subsegmentAlignment="true"
subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
<Representation
id="2256191411271029vd"
mimeType="video/mp4"
codecs="avc1.4D401E"
width="360"
height="640"
frameRate="30"
sar="1:1"
startWithSAP="1"
bandwidth="566620"
FBQualityClass="sd"
FBQualityLabel="360p">
<BaseURL>https://video.frgn7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/44106705_2256191417937695_4868013416159117312_n.mp4?_nc_cat=109&amp;efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjRfaHExX2ZyYWdfMl92aWRlbyJ9&amp;_nc_ht=video.frgn7-1.fna&amp;oh=b4231870aa227938d49b308967577702&amp;oe=5BCF6B02</BaseURL>
<SegmentBase
indexRangeExact="true"
indexRange="957-1084"
FBFirstSegmentRange="1085-138333">
<Initialization range="0-956"/>
</SegmentBase>
</Representation>
<Representation
id="304511600280024v" 
mimeType="video/mp4"
codecs="avc1.4D401F"
width="720"
height="1280"
frameRate="30"
sar="1:1"
startWithSAP="1"
bandwidth="1854960"
FBQualityClass="hd"
FBQualityLabel="720p">
<BaseURL>https://video.frgn7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/43901176_304511603613357_2085028235036327936_n.mp4?_nc_cat=100&amp;efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjRfaHEyX2ZyYWdfMl92aWRlbyJ9&amp;_nc_ht=video.frgn7-1.fna&amp;oh=8902ed723a7bb1de393556396d5d3ff5&amp;oe=5BCF7D38
</BaseURL>
<SegmentBase
indexRangeExact="true"
indexRange="957-1084"
FBFirstSegmentRange="1085-389656">
<Initialization range="0-956"/>
</SegmentBase>
</Representation>
<AdaptationSet
segmentAlignment="true"
lang="und"
subsegmentAlignment="true"
subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
<Representation
id="336089570270236ad"
mimeType="audio/mp4"
codecs="mp4a.40.5"
audioSamplingRate="44100"
startWithSAP="1"
bandwidth="49471">
<AudioChannelConfiguration
schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:    23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011"
value="2"/>
<BaseURL>https://video.frgn7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/43904447_336089580270235_371864079578431488_n.mp4?_nc_cat=1&amp;efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjRfaHExX2ZyYWdfMl9hdWRpbyJ9&amp;_nc_ht=video.frgn7-1.fna&amp;oh=ba2e146d781ce1db2cfe16834ccf08a8&amp;oe=5BCF6BDF
</BaseURL>
<SegmentBase
indexRangeExact="true"
indexRange="881-1008"
FBFirstSegmentRange="1009-13706">
<Initialization range="0-880"/>
</SegmentBase>
</Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
</Period>
</MPD>
```

---

My app works like this. I can download different videos and an audio file. After downloading the videos play without the song. The last item of menu is for audio. If I download it, it comes as audio in mp4 format. Not in mp3 format. So after downloading, I wanna combine the audio to each video.
[image]

Comment: probably just start plaback of audio together with a video?

Comment: I don't get you, sorry.

Comment: the moment you start the video playback, start also the audio playback separetely

Comment: I get it. But the audio mimeType is "audio/mp4". It can't be played two mp4 files together on Android phone.

Comment: why do you think so? Show how you play the video

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: it's strange! when you download the video it probably come with the audio file??? how are you playing your media??? pls show some code.

Comment: So finally after 20 hours we now know your real question. You want to know **how to merge/combine video and audio**. Now my question is if you have tried searching for that before asking?

Comment: Of course I searched. But I don't know how to combine.

Comment: @W.Seun Please check the xml. You can use XMLPullParser to extract them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine Audio with Video - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168774/combine-audio-with-video-android)